# CCAvenue Payment Error code 10002 Merchant Authentication failed. Don't worry... It happens to the best of us

Tags: java, payment-gateway, ccavenue

I am using cc-avenue jsp integration kit in my website. I have used the code which is provided by cc-avenue but when I try to checkout from my site it gives an error

> 10002 Merchant Authentication failed. Don't worry... It happens to
>   the best of us.

Please any one help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Are you using the test account or the actual one?

Answer (score 7):

This error can be caused by an incorrect **merchant ID**, an **incorrect access code**, or if the order originates from an **unregistered URL**. Make sure that all three of these values are correct.

> For your security, CCAvenue does not report exactly which of these three values might be in error.

**Update:**

1. You can find CCAvenue setup for ASP.net from here: http://aravin.net/complete-guide-integrate-ccavenue-payment-gateway-asp-net-website-screenshot/
2. Also, you can find steps to solve the 10002 here: http://aravin.net/how-to-test-ccavenue-payment-gateway-in-localhost-avoid-error-code-10002-merchant-authentication-failed/

Comment: Worked for me as a sub domain was not registered in my case. Thanks

Comment: I have valid registerded url. that is http://blahblah.com. but the request i make is overs https. Can this cause 10002 error.

Answer (score 4):

**The Error code 10002 means that Access code or URL not valid so request you to confirm that you are posting the Access code value to CCAvenue and also confirm that the request URL posting to CCAvenue has to be the same as the registered URL with us, as we are having the URL Validation at our end.**

The post action URL must be https://secure.ccavenue.com/transaction/transaction.do?command=initiateTransaction

Kindly confirm that you're passing the correct API keys in the integration kit.
We would like to inform you that the API keys that are generated in your account, are for the live website URL and live server (i.e. secure.ccavenue.com). Thus, if we receive any request other that the website URL, (e.g. Local host / sub-domain), or for the test server (i.e. https://test.ccavenue.com/transaction/transaction.do?command=initiateTransaction), you will get the merchant authentication failed error.

We request you to kindly check at your end.

Comment: I have valid registerded url. that is blahblah.com. but the request i make is overs https. Can this cause 10002 error.

Answer (score 0):

## Error Code: 10002     Merchant Authentication failed.

## Don't worry... It happens to the best of us.

This might be due to incorrect MERCHANT ID, WORKING KEY or ACCESS CODE. The most likely it is possible due to incorrect URL so to make sure this is implemented on the Registered Domain for Testing URL/Live url for which the API keys are issued.

Please check the registered ccavenue Testing/Live URL for the same.

Comment: I have valid registerded url. that is blahblah.com. but the request i make is overs https. Can this cause 10002 error.

Comment: Sorry for late response if your domain URL (blahblah.com) is registered with ccavenue it should work without any issues on https. it will not work for any other location for example blahblah2.com

Answer (score 0):

Are you using it on localhost?

If you need to test your code from your local machine, you should write to CCAvenue service desk at service@ccavenue.com with your merchant ID and localhost URL to white-list. Else CCAvenue will throw error "Merchant Authentication Failed".

Otherwise this error can be caused by an incorrect access code or if the order originates from an unregistered URL. Make sure that all three of these values are correct.

After your web address gets approved then recheck the new access key and working key

Also use  https://secure.ccavenue.com/transaction/transaction.do?command=initiateTransaction this URL for payments

Answer (score 0):

**I was having same error.**

*Note below points*

1. whitelist your **IP** or **Domain** - ask ccavenue care, they will do whitelist it.
2. it will work default in live envirement for URL `https://secure.ccavenue.com/xyz`
3. for development or test enrolment we need to ask ccavenue to **enable** our merchant id(need to give our merchant id) **for test environment** for   URL `https://test.ccavenue.com/xyz`

Once it enable, then it will work. also double check your merchant_id and access_code too.